# how to merge two excel columns in python using colab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm working on a data-oriented project, we have some cancer measurements, and want to classify with K-means algorithms.

Now I have two basic example datasets, with two-two columns, but the K-means algorithms need only 2 columns, so I decided to concatenate the columns, but how can I do it?

For example fst dataset looks like this:

```
0   2713.9  566.42
1   2718.9  566.42
2   2723.3  566.25
3   2729.5  565.99
4   2735.9  565.83
```

the snd one looks like this:

```
0   6571.5  959.12
1   6571.6  959.13
2   6571.7  959.12
3   6571.7  959.16
4   6571.7  959.15
```

And I want something like this (without the row number of course):

```
0   2713.9  566.42
1   2718.9  566.42
2   2723.3  566.25
3   2729.5  565.99
4   2735.9  565.83
0   6571.5  959.12
1   6571.6  959.13
2   6571.7  959.12
3   6571.7  959.16
4   6571.7  959.15
```

I tried with this:

```
X = ds1[ds1.columns[2:4]].append(ds2[ds2.columns[2:4]])
X
```

and got this:

```
0   2713.9  566.42  NaN     NaN
1   2718.9  566.42  NaN     NaN
2   2723.3  566.25  NaN     NaN
3   2729.5  565.99  NaN     NaN
4   2735.9  565.83  NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
44  NaN     NaN     6571.8  959.01
45  NaN     NaN     6571.7  959.00
46  NaN     NaN     6571.7  958.98
47  NaN     NaN     6571.5  959.00
48  NaN     NaN     6571.4  959.01
```

Also got this with this code:

```
X = pd.concat([ds1[ds1.columns[2:4]], ds2[ds2.columns[2:4]]],  axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False)
```

How can I do this? Is there any method for this, or I have to transform the data in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try via `vstack()`:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((ds1.columns[2:4].values,ds2[ds2.columns[2:4]].values)))
```

**OR**

via `concatenate()`:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((ds1.columns[2:4].values,ds2[ds2.columns[2:4]].values)))
```

**OR**

```
out=ds1[ds1.columns[2:4]].append(ds2[ds2.columns[2:4]]).T.agg(sorted,key=pd.isnull).dropna().T
```

**OR**

You can also rename the name of columns of any 1 dataset so that both subset of df's has same name then use `concat()` or `append()` them

Comment: Thanks, worked this way: `out=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((ds1[ds1.columns[2:4]],ds2[ds2.columns[2:4]].values)))`.